# Calculating maximum power transfer for given circuit

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

Someone sent me this question along with an answer. However I am completely unable to calculate this using either KCL or KVL.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxQbll.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The value for R is 10 ohm for maximum power transfer. But as per my calculation maximum power transfer will be on a value R<sub>infinity</sub>. (With R increasing V<sub>1</sub> increases which in turn will increase current 0.1V<sub>1</sub>)

Comment: Maybe you can share your calculation so we can see where it went wrong? With two separate sources you should use superposition of the two single source results.

Comment: @LarsHankeln That is something I am not able to do. The best I have calculated is P=100*R/(3R+1)^2 . I don't want solution but verification if 10ohm is even an answer.

Comment: @Avezan The answer is, in fact, \$R = 10\: \Omega\$. You've been told, correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the unknown resistance, \$R\$, and the fixed voltage supply are in series, they can be swapped without loss for analysis. The resulting schematic is as simple as the following case:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGHUGi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You only have one node to solve for, making this almost trivial:

$$\frac{V}{R_1=5\:\Omega}+\frac{V}{R}=100\:\text{mS}\cdot\left(V-{-5}\:\text{V}\right)+\frac{-5\:\text{V}}{R}$$

Solve the above equation for \$V\$ and then apply it to the power equation: \$P_R=\frac{\left(V\,-\,{-5}\:\text{V}\right)^2}{R}\$. Take the differential with respect to \$R\$ and then set that equal to zero and solve. You will find the solution to be \$R=10\:\Omega\$.

In sympy:

```
v=Symbol('v')
r=Symbol('r')
solve(Eq(derivative(simplify((solve(Eq(v/5+v/r,.1*(v+5)-5/r),v)[0]+5)**2/r),r),0),r)[0]

10.0000000000000
```

Comment: I cannot understand `100mS` but now have got idea to solve this. For all that time I was doing `max([(r*(5*(1+0.1*r)/(r+5))**2, r) for r in range(5000)])` for verification.

Comment: @Avezan 100 mS means 100 milliSiemens. Not 100 milliseconds. It matches your schematic where you can see "0.1" on the left multiplying the voltage to set the dependent current source.

Comment: Oh sorry for that it was my first ever try on circuit lab schematic. The question was rather simple of a 2nd year graduate where voltage dependent current source was equal to 0.1V<sub>1</sub>.

Comment: @Avezan Yes. I was able to interpret things correctly. The factor, 0.1, has units. These units are Siemens. When you multiply Siemens by Volts you get Amps. Simple dimensional analysis. So the equation is correct and the result still matches what you were told it should be. Sometimes, when someone writes "0.1" they don't give you the units, as you are supposed to "just know" what they are. I did know. Perhaps you didn't understand that. If not, this is something else you'll need to acquire in your head. Dimensional analysis is very important to learn about.

Comment: oh ok, calculation failure. `100mS` is infact `0.1S`, something predetermined in my head was bugging to see `10` or `0.1`, I got all. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: @Avezan Ah. I see. You didn't immediately convert 0.1 S to 100 mS, like I did. Got it.

Comment: @jonk Well done, nice answer (+1)!

Answer (score 3):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course). Besides that the answer of [@jonk](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/38098/jonk) is excellent.

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWeZxT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{n}\cdot\text{V}_1=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

We also know that \$\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2=\text{V}_\text{i}\$.

Now, we can solve for \$\text{V}_1\$:

$$\text{V}_1=\frac{\text{R}_1\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\left(1-\text{n}\text{R}_1\right)}\tag3$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code to find \$(3)\$:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{n*V1 == I1 + I2, I1 == V1/R1, I2 == V2/R2, 
   V1 - V2 == Vi}, {V1, V2, I1, I2}]]

Out[1]={{V1 -> (R1 Vi)/(R1 + R2 - n R1 R2), 
  V2 -> -(((1 - n R1) R2 Vi)/(R1 + R2 - n R1 R2)), 
  I1 -> Vi/(R1 + R2 - n R1 R2), 
  I2 -> -((Vi - n R1 Vi)/(R1 + R2 - n R1 R2))}}
```

So, the power in the resistor \$\text{R}_1\$ is given by:

$$\text{P}_{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1^2}{\text{R}_1}=\left(\frac{\text{R}_1\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\left(1-\text{n}\text{R}_1\right)}\right)^2\cdot\frac{1}{\text{R}_1}=\text{R}_1\cdot\left(\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\left(1-\text{n}\text{R}_1\right)}\right)^2\tag4$$

In order to find the maximum, we can use:

$$\frac{\partial\text{P}_{\text{R}_1}}{\partial\text{R}_1}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_1\left(\text{nR}_2-1\right)\right)\text{V}_\text{i}^2=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{R}_1=\frac{\text{R}_2}{1-\text{n}\text{R}_2}\tag5$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code to find \$(5)\$:

```
In[2]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[Solve[{D[R1 *(Vi/(R1 + R2 - n R1 R2))^2, R1] == 0}, R1]]

Out[2]={{R1 -> R2/(1 - n R2)}}
```

> Using your values, we get:
>
> $$\text{R}_1=\frac{5}{1-\frac{1}{10}\cdot5}=10\space\Omega\tag6$$